# Как запустить фоновую функцию в бооте телеграм построенную на библиотеке aoigram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как запустить фоновую функцию в боте телеграм построенную на библиотеке aoigram? Функция выполняет поиск новых заказов для водителей post запросом на библиотеке requests. Буду очень рад помощи

Comment: Вы знаете / слышали про [многопоточность](https://habr.com/ru/post/149420/)?

Comment: Отмечу, что использовать requests вместе с aiogram будет нерационально. Вместо этого подключите aiohttp в ваш проект.

Comment: отлично, спаси вам, возьму на вооружение